# Best way to find memory leaks in a C program

Tags: c, macos, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to complete a college assignment, and the marking criteria specifies 5% for memory management - specifically for having no memory leaks.

As I understand it, memory leaks in simple C programs, are only caused by pointers which have become abandoned by the program - ie, malloc/calloc/etc calls which are never have a corresponding `free`.

My question is in 3 parts:

1. Whats the simplest way on Solaris
   and OSX to 'prove' that you haven't
   leaked any memory?
2. Does XCode have
   any tools to help determine memory
   leaks?
3. Does the operating system
   release all previously allocated
   memory within a c program once the
   process ends?

Comment: Nr. 1 is more complex then it sounds. It also means you need an fclose for your fopen and destroyFoo() for your createFoo().

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but worth mentioning: your instructor's idea of memleaks may be different from what matters in the real world. A bounded number of unfreed allocations (independent of any data the program processes) are not a real memory leak despite being caught by tools like valgrint, whereas data-dependent allocations that persist after the data is no longer being used, and get cleaned up only on program exit, *are* real leaks despite the fact that no tool can detect them.

Comment: You can try deleaker but it only for windows(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Valgrind](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/) is your friend.

Comment: I cant seem to get Valgrind to build on OSX, and there doesn't seem to be a binary anywhere.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: `brew install valgrind` warns you that `OS X Mavericks or older is required.` Which is OSX 10.9.  The current version is 10.10.4.

Comment: Not sure what I can do about that. (?)

Answer (score 3):

1. For every malloc(), you need to ensure that you have exactly one free().
2. I haven't worked with XCode, but [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=299834) forum entry may help.
3. Yes.  It's still poor form to let your running program 'leak,' however.

In general, it's a good idea to learn how to avoid leaks without using tools like a memory debugger (early on) -- especially for your simple programs. It's painful, however: when it comes to building anything non-trivial you'll want to start learning how to use the more advanced debugging tools (like [Valgrind](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/), as Alex Reynolds suggested in another answer.)

Comment: When referring to other answers, never say "above" or "below", because the order of answers is not fixed.  Just say something like "Alex's answer".

Answer (score 2):

Answer for Mac OS and an example to be avoided (saved you half an hour).

---

Mac OS doesn't come with Valgrind or dmalloc. Moreover, Valgrind has some compatibility issues when trying to get it installed in Sierra.

There is utility called "leaks", which I get it running by this:

```
leaks -atExit --/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libLeaksAtExit.dylib ./a.out
```

Unfortunately, this **doesn't report obvious memory leaks**... Maybe I am using it wrong, but I was just searching for an *easy* way to check that my C program free'd its memory as it should.

If you have time, then *maybe* read and use [Using OSX Leaks for C Programs on the Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747084/using-osx-leaks-for-c-programs-on-the-command-line)

Resources:

1. [Finding Memory Leaks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html)
2. [Using the "leaks" command on a C/C++ executable](https://www.reddit.com/r/macprogramming/comments/7iao6d/using_the_leaks_command_on_a_cc_executable/)

PS: Maybe if used with "iprofiler", then it might be useful, but I didn't had it installed.

Answer (score 0):

there's [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/docs/5.4.3/online/dmalloc.html) too