# Using OSX Leaks for C Programs on the Command Line?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

Can anyone give me any simple syntax for running OSX's `leaks` tool for detecting memory leaks in a compiled C program? I'm on 10.8, so I'm running into serious compatibility issues with `valgrind`.

Most of the stuff I've read about XCode's Leaks/Instruments involves being in an XCode environment -- not something I want to do for my C programs.

Is there a way I can just run leaks on a compiled C program from the command line? If not, are there any other reliable alternatives I can use while waiting for an updated version of valgrind, or do I have to set up a VM with a Linux distro?

Comment: Set up a Linux distro in a VM anyway, it's not much setting up (install VM, download pre-made virtual disk(s) with Linux(es) of your choice (my choice is usually Lubuntu), boot VM to Linux desktop). Such a thing comes in handy quite often...

Comment: Of course... How much of the google searches for "/usr/bin/leaks" and "/usr/bin/malloc_history" have you read?

Comment: As KristianSpangsege said, I tried using `leaks`, I didn't have the `iprofiler`, and experienced the same bad behavior, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940871/2411320) for more. Maybe I don't use it correctly, who knows, the man page didn't help.

Comment: Similar q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67443340/3160967

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `iprofiler` tool ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iprofiler.1.html)) by adding this to the start of your command line:

```
iprofiler -leaks -d $HOME/tmp
```

(where `$HOME/tmp` is where you want the results written).

You can then open up the resulting `.dtps` bundle using *Instruments* to check for leaks (or any of the other 4 checks that `iprofiler` performs).

If you are using *clang* then compile with both `-O3` and `-g` (as *clang* doesn't support `-pg`).

Comment: I tried, but this method unfortunately fails to find obvious leaks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (macOS Catlina 10.15.6):

```
cd /usr/local/lib
ln -s $(xcode-select -p)/usr/lib/libLeaksAtExit.dylib
leaks --atExit -- ./a.out
```

Best to remove the symlink when done.

References:

- https://medium.com/@dr_rost/detect-memory-leaks-on-macos-4cf257529aa
- https://www.reddit.com/r/macprogramming/comments/7iao6d/using_the_leaks_command_on_a_cc_executable/