# Memory Leaks in C (MacOS)

Tags: c, macos, memory-leaks

I'm a C programming student trying to find a way to detect memory leaks on MacOs Mojave.

I know about the existence of Valgrind, but it doesn't support current MacOs releases. After installing Apple Command Line Tools, I tried to run my C program with leaks tool but it doesn´t work... Running this very simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Like this:

```
leaks ./a.out
```

This is the output:

```
leaks[875]: [fatal] unable to read input graph: The data 
 couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

I don´t understand why this happens... How can I use the leaks tool?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747084/using-osx-leaks-for-c-programs-on-the-command-line) helps

Comment: What is iprofiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure is this helpful, but if the C program's status is in running, "leaks" would be available

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  getchar(); // just add to sleep
  return 0;
}
```

run above, then run belows in another terminal

```
leaks a.out
```

you can show related messages

```
Process:         a.out [8724]
Path:            /Users/USER/Documents/*/a.out
Load Address:    0x1078f2000
Identifier:      a.out
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  bash [7876]
...
```

using [PID] is also available in this example

```
leaks 8724
```

---

here is a sample code that memory leak is detected,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
  char* pTmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  test();
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don´t understand how to do that... Could you be more explicit?

Comment: @andrefcptcc34 open two terminals, first one run ./a.out (including getchar() for running status), then move to another terminal, run leaks a.out

Comment: @andrefcptcc34 simply, just run “top”, and remember one pid in running, then run leaks [PID], like this: leaks 8888

Comment: Ok, it worked... But why does it happen? Shouldn't it run at first? Using ```leaks ./a.out```?

Comment: @andrefcptcc34 i tried “leaks ./a.out” + some options, but got a same output message with you, it seems that leaks only working in process level, not a code level

Comment: The leaks tool doesn't show memory leakage when I don't free the malloc...

Comment: @andrefcptcc34 maybe malloc was in main function which was still on stack, did you try with other test function call including malloc?

Answer (score 11):

Unlike Valgrind, the leaks command is designed to find memory leaks in code that is *already running* when the "leaks" command is executed.

In order to get the functionality you are looking for you want the following command:

```sh
leaks -atExit -- ./a.out
```

Comment: Missing a dash ```leaks --atExit -- ./a.out```

Answer (score -2):

## Try this

```
#define malloc(X) my_malloc( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)

void* my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func)
{

    void *p = malloc(size);
    printf ("Allocated = %s, %i, %s, %p[%li]\n", file, line, func, p, size);

    /*Link List functionality goes in here*/

    return p;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn´t the C program... I'm not asking how to allocate memory, it was just a simple example.

Comment: Oh I see, I took it the other way