# MacOS `heap` on C Executable

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

(Using MacOS 14 w/ ARM.) To process a compiled C executable with `leaks` on MacOS, we use:

`leaks -atExit -- <file>`

without the `-atExit --`, an [error is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58013601/22673230).

What is the equivalent for `heap`? On trying:

`heap <file>`

there is a similar error:

`heap[61553]: [fatal] unable to read input graph: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

but `-atExit --` is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'equivalent'.

Use `leaks` ([manpage](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/leaks/osx-10.12.6.php)) to generate a memory graph file, and run `heap` on that output. Thus we use (`<graph>` is a chosen name, `<file>` is the executable):

`leaks -outputGraph=<graph> -atExit -- <file>`

followed by:

`heap <graph>.memgraph`