# How to use leaks command-line tool to find memory leaks?

Tags: c, macos, debugging, memory-leaks, command-line-tool

`leaks` command-line tool will report

- the address of the leaked memory
- the size of the leak (in bytes)
- the contents of the leaked buffer

like the following:

```
Process:         checker [84357]
Path:            /path/to/program
Load Address:    0x104703000
Identifier:      checker
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  zsh [64610]

Date/Time:       2019-11-30 18:43:06.864 -0800
Launch Time:     2019-11-30 18:42:58.593 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/leaks

Physical footprint:         300K
Physical footprint (peak):  300K
----

leaks Report Version: 3.0
Process 84357: 161 nodes malloced for 17 KB
Process 84357: 3 leaks for 64 total leaked bytes.

Leak: 0x7fdf5b400350  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x10470e000
Leak: 0x7fdf5b4027c0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x10470e000
Leak: 0x7fdf5b402810  size=32  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x10470e000
```

My question is, how can I use these information to actually track down and find which malloc calls in my source code doesn’t have corresponding `free()` calls?
How can I find out which source file / where in the source file?
Do I need to change the value of some environment variables like `MallocStackLogging` or `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact`?

Comment: Try looking at the "man leaks" command documentation page in Terminal, explains some things. Type `man leaks`. https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/leaks/

Comment: @Raymond I already did, but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

It took me a while, but once I figured this all out it works great:

- I used to use `valgrind`, until it couldn't run on my newer osx version. I was looking for a similarly convenient command-line approach to tracing memory leaks (could use Instruments instead, but it is heavyweight and UI-driven, both of which annoy me)
- Using `leaks -atExit` tells me which leaks exist, but not where any leaked allocation came from
- MallocStackLogging creates logs that can tell me where the leaked allocations came from, but the logs are automatically deleted when the program exits, and `leaks -atExit` runs, obviously, at exit

So you have to run MallocStackLogging, pause your program, then run leaks:

1. Open a terminal and set MallocStackLogging: `export MallocStackLogging=1`
2. At the end of the program, before it exists, add a line of code to pause it by reading from stdin, then recompile: `fscanf(stdin, "c"); // wait for user to enter input from keyboard`
3. Run your program and wait for it to pause
4. In a separate terminal, output the leak allocations by running `leaks my_program_name` (or alternatively, find your pid: `ps aux | grep my_program_name` and then run `leaks <pid>`).

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Set environment variable `MallocStackLogging` to true, run program, then run `leaks`.
This will print a stack trace of where the leaked memory was allocated.

The way I did it is:

1. `export MallocStackLogging=1`
2. In the `main` function, add the following code right before returning.
     `system("leaks executablename");` .
3. Run program.

Answer (score 2):

You can save memory graph file with the `leaks` command. If malloc stack logging is enabled the graph will include stack traces.

If your program is a long-running process chances are you want to compare memory usage at different point in time, which can be also done with the `leaks` commands.

- in one terminal, run you program with stack logging: `MallocStackLogging=1 ./myprogram`
- in another terminal, run `leaks --outputGraph=g1 myprogram`; this will save `g1.memgraph` file
- (optional) after some time run `leaks --outputGraph=g2 myprogram`
- you can now kill `myprogram`
- view the results with either `leaks g1.memgraph` or `leaks --diffFrom=g1.memgraph g2.memgraph`

Comment: How do I use `leaks` for Python scripts?